# I'm encountering an issue with the Android TV TvProvider not working successfully

Tags: android, android-tvprovider

I've been developing according to the official Android TV content discovery documentation at [Document](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery).

While I was able to achieve success on an emulator running API Level 28, my attempts have failed on emulators running API Level 31 and 34.

Has anyone experienced similar issues, or does anyone have suggestions on how to address compatibility with newer API levels?

In my efforts to troubleshoot, I downloaded the Android sample from [Sample](https://github.com/android/tv-samples/tree/main/ReferenceAppKotlin) and installed it on emulators running API Level 30, API Level 28, and a Google TV device running API Level 31. Out of these attempts, only the emulator with API Level 28 was successful in displaying the content as expected.